# .NET the following 2 lines give a compile error, why?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following 2 lines in ASP.NET in VB.NET (For C# just replace the world 'Dim' with 'var') that I got from an example.

```
 Dim tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName()
 Dim tmpFileStream = File.OpenWrite(tmpFile)
```

I get an error on `File.OpenWrite(tmpFile)` that says 'Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'File' accepts this number of arguments'. Can anyone explain why this error is happening? I tried looking at documentation and can't seem to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: any reason you don't want to declare the type?

Comment: I think we need to know what Path and File are.. their declarations are not shown.

Comment: But that is only 2 lines....

Comment: Typo, 2 lines, not 3. The reason I didn't declare the types was because I just converted them from C#. The converter did not include the types, I added them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that the error message is specifying `File` and not `OpenWrite`.  It looks like there is another `File` in context which has a higher precedence than `System.IO.File`.  This is likely the source of the error.  Try using a fully qualified name here

```
Dim tmpFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(tmpFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the top of your code file:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Also, as Daniel suggested, it can be helpful, by making the code more clear, to specify your types, for instance:

```
Dim tmpFile As String = Path.GetTempFileName()
Dim tmpFileStream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(tmpFile)
```

In the latest versions of VB, it will automatically infer the type for you, so it will make tmpFile to be a `String` type variable, even though you didn't specify.  However, in older versions of VB, it will just make it a base `Object` type, in which case it would not be able to determine which overload to use.

Comment: Don't think that is the problem.  Both `File` and `Path` exist in the `System.IO` namespace.  If this was the problem the OP should be getting an error on `Path` as well